# Open protected excel file too slow

Tags: python, excel, protected, xlwings

I developed a script, that opens a huge load of protected (not password protected, just protected) excel files using xlwings, reads one column in each file and writes it to a dict, then closes. It works without producing any errors, but it's suuuper slow.
Is there a faster way than my code below?

```
import xlwings as xw

def unprotect_xls(filename, date):

    workbook = xw.Book(filename)
    sheet = workbook.sheets['Table1']

    error_length[date] = dict(zip(range(1,21), sheet['BN7:BN26'].value))

    workbook.close()


#### not working example ####
file_names = ['file1', 'file2', ..., 'file999']
dates = ['date1', ...]

new_files = len(file_names) 

# make dict
error_length = {}

# open excel in background
app = xw.App(visible=False)

#fill dict
for i in range(new_files):
    unprotect_xls(file_names[i], dates[i])

app.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `openpyxl` or `xlrd` for this task? You can also use `pandas.read_excel` function which uses one of these packages under the hood. `xlwings` is great if you need to interact with Excel but if you only need to batch read cell values, the reader libraries may be much better suited.

Comment: I tried both but since I have old .xls files, openpyxl doesn't work and xlrd is not able to fulfill the task. Only xlwings was able to access my files.

Comment: What's the issue with xlrd?

Comment: a warning is produced: WARNING *** file size (192888) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero   , an empty dataframe is created. couldn't find a solution to it

Comment: WARNING *** file size (192888) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512) WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749802/python-with-pandas-file-size-44546-not-512-multiple-of-sector-size-512

Comment: thank you, but already found that one. the warning is indeed not printed, but there is still just an empty dataframe created.

Comment: found a reddit post, where someone said, that the 'shitty xls file' should be opened, saved and then closed. Seems to work. I just have to find out now, what is faster, xlwings or the other procedure.

Comment: wrote a test file; xlwings is faster than the workaround